# resolve.conf (generated) wrong order? (2 routers)

Tags: raspbian, archlinux

I have 2 routers in my network.
A) The one issued by my ISP (limited settings, had even to ask to get portforwarding settings), which is alo my modem.
B) My own router (wher i set my DHCP etc)

Now the generated resolve.txt on raspberrian and archlinux list:

```
domain local
nameserver <IP of A>
nameserver <IP of B>
```

As in understand it this is the order it will try to use when resolving names, but her it schould try my internal B before trying to resolve using A.

PS: Both subnetmasks are 255.255.255.0
Router A has 192.168.0.1
Router B has 192.168.1.1
All devices are in the 192.168.1.### range.

PPS: Archlinux is setup to use networkmanager, not a manual configured dhcpcd

Answer (score 0):

NetworkManager may use dnsmasq for dhcp and to handle dns lookups.

I noticed that dnsmasq reverses the order of nameservers. Look at your logs. That would show up better in log if we also set dnsmasq to call dns servers in parallel:

```
#/etc/dnsmasq.conf
#all-servers

#/etc/dnsmasq.d/laptop.conf
all-servers
log-queries=extra
log-async=100
log-dhcp

#/etc/dnsmasq.d/servers.conf
server=66.187.76.168
server=162.248.241.94
server=165.227.22.116

/var/log/dnsmasq.log--

Mar 14 02:14:20 dnsmasq[3216]: 71700 127.0.0.1/38951 cached firefox.settings.services.mozilla.com is <CNAME>
Mar 14 02:14:20 dnsmasq[3216]: 71700 127.0.0.1/38951 forwarded firefox.settings.services.mozilla.com to 165.227.22.116
Mar 14 02:14:20 dnsmasq[3216]: 71700 127.0.0.1/38951 forwarded firefox.settings.services.mozilla.com to 162.248.241.94
Mar 14 02:14:20 dnsmasq[3216]: 71700 127.0.0.1/38951 forwarded firefox.settings.services.mozilla.com to 66.187.76.168
```

...order of calls is reversed in log lines!

I got rid of systemd-resolved to rely on dnsmasq.